# Entity Framework changes my default database name

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and it changes my defualt database name for examle BLOODGROUP_08bb0dde1a5b4193828358a79cb01315.

My context class is:

```
  public BloodGroupContext()
        : base("BloodGroup")
    {

    }
```

and my connection string is:

```
 <add name="BloodGroup" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BloodGroup.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I searched for the answer but I couldn't find anything.
I currently run microsoft sql server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
  public BloodGroupContext()
        : base("name=BloodGroup")
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the initial catalog of your connection string?  This will set your database name.  Try setting this to your existing database name.